# How to determine the position of the item on screen? Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

How to determine the position of the item on screen and that its position adjusts to the screen resolution

In MainActivity I added

```
App.ScreenWidth = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
```

and set value in App.cs

In CustomMap in Android project I wont set position compass on google maps whit margin on the left 16dp and from the top 54dp

```
googleMap.UiSettings.CompassEnabled = true;
        googleMap.UiSettings.MapToolbarEnabled = true;
        googleMap.UiSettings.MyLocationButtonEnabled = false;
        googleMap.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = false;
        Android.Views.View compass = FindViewWithTag("GoogleMapCompass");
        compass.SetX(????);
        compass.SetY(????);
```

Example I wont move compass

[image]

Comment: What is your goal? Is it to put a button on the the top left position? Can your share some code so that we can help you?

Comment: @Daniel I add picture, maybe this help you

Comment: This could be a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876251/google-maps-xamarin-moving-the-compass-button